# monotone function on open interval is continuous except possibly at a countable number of points

Tags: real-analysis

Here is the proof from Royden's book.

> Assume $f$ is increasing. Furthermore, assume $(a,b)$ is bounded and
>   $f$ is increasing on the closed interval $[a,b]$. Otherwise, express
>   $(a,b)$ as the union of an ascending sequence of open, bounded
>   intervals, the closures of which are contained in $(a,b)$, and take
>   the union of the discontinuities in each of this countable collection
>   of intervals. For each $x_0 \in (a,b)$, $f$ has a limit from the left
>   and from the right at $x_0$. Define $$f(x_0^-) = \lim_{x \to x_0^-}
>  f(x) = sup \{f(x)| a < x < x_0\}, $$ $$f(x_0^+) = \lim_{x \to x_0^+}
>  f(x) = sup \{f(x)| x_0 < x < b\}. $$Since $f$ is increasing, $f(x_0^-)
>  \leq f(x_0^+)$. The function $f$ fails to be continuous at $x_0$ if
>   and only if $f(x_0^-) < f(x_0^+)$, in which case we define the open
>   "jump" interval $J(x_0)$ by $$J(x_0) = \{y|f(x_0^-) < y <
>  f(x_0^+)\}.$$ Each jump interval is contained in the bounded interval
>   $[f(a), f(b)]$ and the collection of jump intervals is disjoint.
>   Therefore, for each natural number $n$, there are only a finite number
>   of jump intervals of length greater than $1/n$. Thus the set of points
>   of discontinuity of $f$ is the union of a countable collection of
>   finite sets and therefore is countable.

It seems the book is assuming that $[f(a), f(b)]$ being finite, then what if it is not finite? i.e., $[f(a), f(b)]$ is of the form $[f(a), \infty]$. Can I write $[f(a), \infty] = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty [f(a), k]$ and say for each number n, there are only countably sum of finite jump intervals of length greater than $\frac{1}{n}$ in each $[f(a), k]$, thus there are countably many jump intervals in $[f(a), \infty]$.

Comment: Since $f$ is a real-valued function, $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are real numbers, and $f(b)-f(a)$ is necessarily a real number and hence finite.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If $f$ is an extended real valued function, is my argument right? Does the theorem still hold?

Comment: Yes, it does. This is what the third sentence of the proof is getting at. If $f$ is unbounded as $x\to b^-$, let $\langle b_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a strictly increasing sequence in $(a,b)$ converging to $b$. The proof shows that $f$ has only countably many discontinuities on each $[a,b_n]$, so there are only countably many on $[a,b]$. (You have the right idea, but it’s better to work in the domain of the function.)